# Angular view not updating according to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

My Angular view is not updating when I update my model. I have tried calling $scope.apply() to no avail.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in Day.items track by $index">
   <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
          {{key}}
      </div>
      <select ng-model="value[$index].itemName" ng-options="item as item for item in Equipment.{{key}}">
         <option value="">Select Option</option>
      </select>
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="number" ng-model="value[$index].value" placeholder="Amount/Value">
   </label>

   <button class="button button-balanced button-outline button-block" ng-click="AddItem(Day,key)">
       Add {{key}}
    </button>
</div>
```

And then in my controller:

```
$scope.AddItem = function(day,key) {
    day.items[key].push({itemName : '', value : ''});
}
```

What am I doing wrong? If I log out day.items[key] from the AddItem method, it has been successful in pushing a new object into the array, it's just not displaying it.

Comment: What's your controller named? Make sure it's spelled right. Also, I don't see `ng-controller` anywhere in your HTML. You need to have `ng-controller="<the name of your controller>"` as an attribute to the element you wish to assign the controller to.

Comment: The controller is definitely working, it's being specified in my routing.

Comment: But how is the controller attached to your html?

Answer (score 0):

To 2-way binds the model to the controllers variable you'll need to specify in the ng-model the scope.array and not directly the value.

I can't test it right now, but it should be something like :

```
<label class="item item-input" ng-repeat="(key, value) in Day.items">
    {{key}}<input type="text" ng-model="Day.items[key].itemName">
</label >
```

**update**

I don't know how your app should exaclty look like, so compare your problem with this fiddle. In the fiddle, the model is correctly binded.

**[--FIDDLE--](http://jsfiddle.net/g37cj0f3/)**